# Keep Getting Segmentation Fault (core dump) when trying to print array

Tags: c, arrays, string, segmentation-fault, strtok

Not sure why I'm getting a fault on this, can someone please help me out. Also, I know about the sizes being different and not correct, I'm not worried about that right now. I'm just trying to test something.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


        char csvDest[100] = "1000,cap_net_raw,cap_sys_admin";
        char *tokptr = strtok(csvDest,",");
        char *csvArray[100];

        int i = 0;
        while(tokptr != NULL){
              csvArray[i++] = tokptr;
              tokptr = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }

        int j;
        for(j=0; j < i; j++){
            printf("%s\n", csvArray[j]);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: csvDest is not necessarily a null-terminated string, which strtok requires.

Comment: @Cheetaiean, as written by OP, `csvDest` is NUL-terminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a call to `strtok`.

Replace

```
              tokptr = (NULL, ",");
```

with

```
              tokptr = strtok(NULL, ",");
```

---

You cannot print 100 strings unless they have been assigned.  You should replace

```
        for(i=0; i < 100; i++){
            printf("%s\n", csvArray[i]);
        }
```

with

```
        for(int j=0; j < i; j++){
            printf("%s\n", csvArray[j]);
        }
```

Comment: sorry that was a typo as well. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I appreciate it, that still didn't solve the seg fault error

Comment: @ldd12345 please review and re-post your current sources into the question.  (I am not seeing any more segfaults.)  Note that `i` was replaced by `j` everywhere in the print loop...

Comment: made the changes you asked me to make.

Comment: sorry fixed it, check now

Comment: looks ok, runs fine for me.  do you  still have a segfault with this code?

Comment: please include your terminal session in the question, including when you compile and when you run the program.

Comment: How not sure how to do that.

Comment: what environment/ide/toolchain are you using to compile and test your program?

Comment: I'm on a virtual machine box on a mac using ubuntu

Comment: are you using `gcc` to compile inside a shell terminal?

Comment: your program, as currently posted in the question, works fine.  either your `program.c` does not match the code in the question, or you have not recompiled it following the most recent fixes.

Comment: You're right, ran it on my mac it works perfectly but doesn't work in ubuntu... weird

Comment: I also compiled and ran on a mac and on ubuntu 18 and works ok on both systems.

Comment: Yeah for whatever reason it won't work on ubuntu for me, works perfectly on my mac IDK

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop does not set `i` back to the beginning of the array.  I.e., set `i` to 0 before accessing `csvArray` in the `printf`.  As is, dereferencing the array is accessing a pointer that has not yet been set.

Comment: That was a typo. I am still getting the segmentation fault.